# missing : after property id Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander = function() {

Tags: javascript, extjs

Okay, so I have spent several hours combing through this code and still can't find where this error is generating from. The error that Firefox console shows me is that this missing colon is found on line 7 in column 5. Can someone please help a girl out? Thank you in advance.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
enabled: true
});

Ext.application( {
controllers: [ "Links" ],
    Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander: function() {
        var expanderVariableScopes = new Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander({
                tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
'<p><span class="boldText" style="text-decoration: underline;">Form Scope</span><ul style="padding:0 0 0 5px;">',
'<tpl for="form_scope"><li><span class="boldText">{key}:</span> {value}</li></tpl>',
'</ul></p><br />',
'<p><span class="boldText" style="text-decoration: underline;">URL Scope</span><ul style="padding:0 0 0 5px;">',
'<tpl for="url_scope"><li><span class="boldText">{key}:</span> {value}</li></tpl>',
'</ul></p>'
                )
 }),
paginator: new YAHOO.widget.Paginator({
     containers: [ 'sessionPaginator' ],
     initialPage: $('#session-initial-page').val(),
     rowsPerPage: $('#session-rows-per-page').val(),
     totalRecords: $('#session-total-records').val()
});
storeAccessLog: new Ext.data.Store({
    baseParams: { limit: 25, method: 'account_session_access_log' },
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        disableCaching: true,
        method: "GET",
        url: "ajax/account.cfc"
    }),
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: "DATA",
        totalProperty: "META.totalRecords",
        fields: [ 'log_id', 'cdate', 'session_id', 'request_type', 'filename', 'user_agent', 'form_scope', 'url_scope', 'account_id', 'accountholder' ]
    }),
    remoteSort: true,
    sortInfo: {
        field: 'cdate',
        direction: 'DESC'
    }
}),
storeAuditEntries: new Ext.data.Store({
    baseParams: { method: 'session_audit_entries' },
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        disableCaching: true,
        method: "GET",
        url: "ajax/account.cfc"
    }),
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: "DATA",
        totalProperty: "META.totalRecords",
        fields: [ 'AUDIT_TEXT', 'AUDIT_DATETIME' ]
    })
}),

$(window).resize(function() {
oWindow.center();   
});

 paginator.subscribe("changeRequest", function (newState) {
            window.location.href = "accounts-view-activity.cfm?#request.qString#&sort=#url.sort#&dir=#url.dir#&initialPage=" + newState.page;
        });

paginator.render();

$('.detailslink')
.button({
    icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-plusthick' },
    text: false
 })
.click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    storeAccessLog.extraParams("session_id", $this.val());
    storeAccessLog.load({ params: { start: 0 } });

    storeAuditEntries.extraParams("session_id", $this.val());
    storeAuditEntries.load();

    oWindow.show()
});

$('#accountForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
name: "SPOT"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `=` operator where you should have used the `:` operator.

When you are defining an object the way you are doing above, the expected syntax is:

```
var obj = {
    prop1: value1,
    prop2: value2
    ...
};
```

In your case,

`Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander = function() {` should be changed to `Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander: function() {`

`paginator = new YAHOO.widget.Paginator({` should be changed to `paginator: new YAHOO.widget.Paginator({`

and so on..

Comment: on which line should the = operator be changed to a :

Comment: Your `Ext.application(..)` call takes an object. The properties of that object should be defined as `keyName: Value`. I've given 2 example correction points in the answer itself.

Comment: I made the suggested changes but I'm still getting the same error message.